# CustomView with xml doesn't show up on screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add my custom view to the main activity's xml.
I have created the following xml for the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Testing custom view"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And created the following class in which the above xml is inflated:

```
public class TestView extends LinearLayout {
public TestView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.test_name, null);

}
```

And in the xml of the main activity I have added the custom view like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

<com.example.myapplication.TestView
    android:id="@+id/submit_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I am running the app, I am getting an empty screen. It's not showing the textview which displays "Testing custom view".
Any help would much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: set background color TestView then check its diplay or not

Comment: No, its not displaying. Changed the colour, but not displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view inflation code in your custom view looks wrong.Try it the way given below.

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_color_options, this, true);
```